# Не загружается селект через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, html, javascript

Всем привет, нашел в сети пример и хочу его исправить под свои нужнды...

html...

```
`<form method="post" action="post.php" id="filterform">
        <select name="filter_id" id="filter_id">
            <option value="0">- seleziona filtro -</option>
            <?=$query->selectFiltri()?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select name="tipologia" id="tipologia" disabled="disabled">
            <option value="0">- seleziona tipoligia -</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </form>`
```

ajax...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#filter_id').change(function () {
    var filter_id = $(this).val();
    if (filter_id == '0') {
        $('#tipologia').html('<option>- выберите город -</option>');
        $('#tipologia').attr('disabled', true);
        return(false);
    }
    $('#tipologia').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#tipologia').html('<option>загрузка...</option>');
    var url = 'filter.php';
    $.get(
        url,
        "filter_id=" + filter_id,
        function (result) {
            if (result.type == 'error') {
                alert('error');
                return(false);
            }
            else {
                var options = '';
                $(result.tipologi).each(function() {
                    options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('id') + '">' + $(this).attr('nome_corto') + '</option>';
                });
                $('#tipologia').html(options);
                $('#tipologia').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        },
        "json"
    );
 });
 });
```

php...

```
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "000", "000");

if (!$sql) {
    return "MySQL сервер недоступен! ".mysql_error();
} else {
    $select = mysql_select_db("000", $sql);

    if (!$select) {
        return "Нет соединения с БД".mysql_error();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

$filter_id = @intval($_GET['filter_id']);

$regs=mysql_query("SELECT id, nome_corto FROM criteri WHERE id_filter=$filter_id AND meta=Tipologia");

if ($regs) {
    $num = mysql_num_rows($regs);      
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $num) {
       $regions[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($regs);   
       $i++;
    }     
    $result = array('tipologi'=>$regions);  
}
else {
    $result = array('type'=>'error');
}
print json_encode($result);
```

После выбора в первом селекте вся работа застывает во втором селекте на слове загрузка! И все не могу понять почему!

**Обновление**

```
function selectFiltri() {
        $this->Connect();

        $select = mysql_query("select id, seo_name from filtri");

        if($select) {

            if(mysql_num_rows($select)) {
                 while ($r = mysql_fetch_object($select))
                 $opt .= '<option value="'.$r->id.'">'.$r->seo_name.'</option>';
            } else {
                 $opt = '<option value="0">0</option>';
            }
            echo $opt;
        } else {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    }
```

Comment: > нашел в сети пример...

Кто-то совсем обнаглел.

> Я "скопипастил". Помогите разобраться в том, что "скопипастил".

Это что?

     @intval($_GET['filter_id']);

Comment: это чтоб id элемента получить используем!

Comment: Я думаю  @romeo хотел спросить зачем Вы используете @

Comment: это не я использую это в примере так, я хочу разобраться и понять, выше описан вопрос! ажакс зависает на строке загрузка! помогите разобраться!!!

Comment: анализируйте запросы в консоли (в хроме f12 -> network). Смотрите что приходит в ответе сервера и что уходит на сервер

Comment: я никогда не анализаровал, хоть подскажите на сто смотреть там и что анализировать, там есть Name Path filter.php?filter_id=19 Method Get Status 200 OK и т.д. но что с этим делать не знаю
нсли я вообще правильно анализировал то в ответ вообще ничего не приходит! но почему если вроде все верно

Comment: @kiberchainik, а пробовали прямой url давать, а не просто filter.php? Такой файл вообще присутствует? Я бы к get добавил проверку на ошибку и думаю это бы все разрешило.

Comment: лазил, лазил и налазил что ошибка в этой страке if (result.type == 'error') {
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null

Comment: $query->selectFiltri() Где и как у вас объявляется класс query? Приведите его код

Answer (score 2):

Вы заменяете свой `<select>` на `<option>` - `$('#tipologia').html('<option>загрузка...</option>');`
Зачем?

**Например**, нам нужно получить все страны, а после получить города данной страны, которую мы выбрали. Подгрузим в первый select страны, а после выбора в первом селекте (используя обработчик события onchange) подгрузим города для этой страны.

Сделайте так:

HTML

```
Страна:<br>
<select class="input" id="country" onchange="GetCities($('#country option:selected').attr('id'));">
  <option id="0">не выбрано</option>
</select><br><br>

Город:<br>
<select class="input" id="city">
  <option id="0">не выбрано</option>
</select><br><br>
```

jQuery

```
function GetCountries() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            for(var i = 0; i < [число - количество стран]; i++) {
                $('#country').append('<option id="'+res.items[i].id+'">'+res.items[i].title+'</option>');
            };
        }
    });

}

GetCountries();

function GetCities(country_id) {

    $('#city option:not(:first)').remove();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'country_id':country_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
            for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                $('#city').append('<option id="'+res.items[i].id+'">'+res.items[i].title+'</option>');
            };
        }
    });

}
```

Пояснения:

```
res.items[i].id - это массив идентификаторов полученных стран
res.items[i].title - это массив наименований полученных стран
```

Вам остается лишь составить ответ в своем PHP файле ajax.php с помощью ассоциотивного массива и отправить в формате json с помощью PHP функции

`echo json_encode($array);`

**Будьте внимательны, все файлы должны быть в кодировке `UTF-8 без BOM`!**, которую можно изменить с помощью Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Вы бы указали, что за ответ от сервера приходит.

В хроме - F12/network и выполните ваш ajax запрос. Где-то в этой вкладке будет показан результат.
Скорее всего - он даже не является валидным json-м, по крайней мере я не вижу его создания в коде php.
А если и явлется - для json потребуется getJSON, а не get, нет? 
Если же требуется получить не json, а html - в result также не должно быть указанного свойства (ЕМНИП, get выдает простую строку)